compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4' is not included in lib folder of war file
I have added the dependencies in dependencies.gradle ,I have two versions of commons-lang ,but only the latest version is getting included in the war file.
commons-lang3.3 is getting included ,but not commons-lang2.4.
I have used compile,compileonly and providedcompile but still facing issue.
I have used compile,compileonly and providedcompile but still facing issue.
